# Can Android Things work with Orange Pi 2G IoT?

Tags: iot, android-things, orange-pi

Will Android Things run on [OrangePi 2G IoT](http://www.orangepi.org/OrangePi2GIOT/) board?

Answer (score 2):

> Will Android Things run on OrangePi 2G IoT board.

It's not clear what exactly you're asking, so there are 2 possible options below:

- If you mean whether *Android Things* **can** currently run on the board, then the answer would be **No**. The board [is not currently supported](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms) by the *Android Things* project.
- If you mean whether *Google* is going to support the platform in the future, then you should contact *Google* about that or fill in a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192720&template=848805).

Comment: I was asking about first one. Thanks